# Cloud Front Distribution - Error granting read permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to create a cloud front web distribution endpoint pointing to my S3 bucket. When I created this distribution , I am trying to set 
"Grant Read Permissions on Bucket" as "Yes, Update Bucket Policy". However this is getting reset back to "No , I will update permissions". I am unable to access the object that I stored in my S3 bucket as I have restricted access at the bucket level. How can I update this property to enable me get access to the S3 object?

This question seems to be already asked [here](https://acloud.guru/forums/aws-certified-solutions-architect-associate/discussion/-L7OyDJondq1_yIMFSp6/hi,_i_followed_the_instruction) , but I don't see any solution.

Comment: I seem to have figured out the issue. I was using the bucket name after cloud front endpoint. I am able to view the obejct when I remove the bucket name after cloud front endpoint. However I am not sure why I see the "Grant Read Permissions on Bucket" as no when I click edit.

Comment: "Grant Read Permissions on Bucket" => "Yes" *really* means "I want the console to modify the bucket ACL automatically when I save the changes on this page."  Then it reverts to "No" because this isn't actually a CloudFront attribute/setting -- it's just a helper capability provided by the AWS console.

Comment: Thanks Michael, is a user created temporarily when the bucket is accessed via cloud front ?

Comment: It's not exactly a "user" -- it's an entity called an [Origin Access Identity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html).  An OAI is a principal that can sign requests on the "back side" of CloudFront on their way to S3.  OAIs have no accessible credentials (the credentials are known only to S3 and CloudFront) and can't be used for any other purpose.  Check your bucket policy and you should find evidence of one.